# Creating a column in a table based on aggregation (without creating another table)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery

I have a table called `Sets` for LEGO:

| set_number (Primary Key) | set_name | other_fields |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Firetruck | abc |
| 234 | Star Wars | abc |

I have another table called `Parts` for LEGO:

| part_number (Primary Key) | name | set_number (references set_number from Sets) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Truck Roof | 123 |
| 2 | Truck Body | 123 |
| 3 | Neimoidian Viceroy Robe | 234 |

I want to create another column in the `Sets` table to indicate the number of unique parts the particular set has.

I was able to output the number of unique parts with the following:

```
SELECT s.set_number, COUNT(*) AS num_diff_parts
FROM Sets s, Parts p
WHERE p.set_number = s.set_number
GROUP BY s.set_number
```

This outputs the following table (let's call it `results`):

| set_number | num_diff_parts |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 |
| 234 | 1 |

However, I wonder if I can put the column (`num_diff_parts`) into the Sets table as a new column, instead of having to run this query every time when I need this information, or create another table just to contain the content of the `results` table.

Ideally, the `Sets` table should look like this:

| set_number (Primary Key) | set_name | other_fields | num_diff_parts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Firetruck | abc | 2 |
| 234 | Star Wars | abc | 1 |

I've also tried to do `GROUP BY` on multiple fields, but I don't think that's safe to do as those fields can have repeats and will throw off the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  distinct 
        set_number
       ,set_name
       ,other_fields
       ,count(*) over(partition by set_number) as num_diff_parts
from    Sets join Parts using(set_number)
```

| set_number | set_name | other_fields | num_diff_parts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Firetruck | abc | 2 |
| 234 | Star Wars | abc | 1 |

We can also `count()` before joining the tables.

```
with parts_cnt as (
                  select   set_number
                          ,count(*) as num_diff_parts
                  from     Parts
                  group by set_number
                  )
select  *
from    Sets join parts_cnt using(set_number)
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OcXu81vx)

Comment: When I do SELECT DISTINCT set_number, ..., I still have duplicates for some reason.

Comment: I don't know without seeing your query, but I added another solution for you.

Comment: I think this is because DISTINCT deduplicates records, not values of set_number. I tried a GROUP BY on set_number, but it returned all 1's for num_diff_parts for some reason.

Comment: Yep, doing a count taking advantages of the fact that each part belongs to a single set gets the job done. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> However, I wonder if I can put the column (num_diff_parts) into the Sets table as a new column, instead of having to run this query every time when I need this information

I would recommend using a view ; with this technique, the information is always available, and you don’t need to keep it up to date by yourself.

In MySQL, a correlated subquery comes handy to efficiently compute the count of parts per set :

```
create view v_sets as
select s.*, 
    (
        select count(*)
        from parts p
        where p.set_number = s.set_number
    ) num_diff_parts
from sets s
```

Comment: covers the case of _instead of having to run this query every time_ perfectly!